# Django Forms query

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have created a app using the following Model

models.py

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Request(models.Model):
    job_reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_reference

class Device(models.Model):
    Vendor = models.ForeignKey('Vendor')
    Model = models.ForeignKey('Model')
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)
    is_encrypted = models.BooleanField()
    is_medical = models.BooleanField()
    request_job_reference = models.ForeignKey('Request')
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

When i go to the admin page I can add new devices which displayed each of the fields and the "Vendor" and "Model" allows me to either select an existing entry or has a plus icon to add a new entry (which is great)
[Django_Admin_form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR81V.png)

When i create a form for my app

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . models import Device

class AddDevice(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('Vendor', 'Model', 'device_id', 'is_encrypted', 'is_medical', 'submitted')
```

The form on my webpage display ok however there is no option to insert a new entry to "Vendor" or "Model".
[Webpage Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Eg3.png)
I have looked on other posts on here as users have had the same issue and it's been suggested to use "ModelChoiceField" but unfortunately it still doesn't make any sense to me. Either i'm completely missing something or I have setup my models in a way which is making things harder for myself.

Can anyone explain how I can go about doing this?

Comment: The ability to add a new entry to the referenced model in the ForeignKey is specific to Django admin, there is no reason to think that this would happen in a ModelForm on your webpage